# Would a NoSQL DB be more efficient than a relational DB for storing JSON objects?

Tags: database, nosql, json, relational-database

I am using a library that returns a JSON object (as a string, but I think that's standard), and I would like to store the contents of this object into a local database.

I'm fairly fresh-faced in terms of interfacing with DBs, but I can find my way around.  I was using a MySQL database to store the data, but this involved using methods to extract the fields of the raw object, and slicing and dicing.

I'm wondering if it would be more efficient to use a NoSQL solution to store the data, as it's already in the right form.

Comment: Have you seen [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)?

Comment: @Joe I've been dabbling with MongoDB over the past few days, I think they are similar?

Comment: I think it depends on the amount of data you have :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The decision of whether to use relational DB or non-relational (document/OO/graph) database should not be based on the representation of the data (JSON/BSON/XML/...), but on the operations you intend to preform on the data.

If you have a strict schema, and you need to execute SQL queries - You should use relational DB. Otherwise, you may consider other options.

Look [here](http://nosql-database.org/) to consider your options.

Comment: Great link.  I would be likely be inserting data about as often as I would be retrieving it, would that change anything?

Comment: The main question remains how would you search for the data you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

well that really depend on your need. for small data you can live with the RDBMS, but for a real system n big data you need have object database. your question can be narrowed down to ODBMS from no-sql.

**Cache DB** from intersystems is a good candidate for solution. cache is object database with no strictness on the schema. here your objects can be mapped to db objects. so you have 1-to-1 mapping and therefore no translation (slicing) is required.

as you have mentioned Json you can also use total free solution from intersystems **GloblasDB** which have its bindings to Java.

as mentioned earlier this totally depends on your need what system you are building.

Comment: Thanks for the two ideas.  I ran through a bunch of the ones that Lior had posted above, too.  There are a ton of options!